# Trying to get C++/WinRT non UWP program to recognize bluetooth LE devices: specific failure at get_weak() (error:not defined)

Tags: windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm taking a shot at using C++/WinRT to find and communicate with Bluetooth LE devices in a non-UWP app.

(I'm trying to avoid UWP, as there appear to be some constraints on what you can do with it, and it looks kind of bloated to me.)

My background is a lot of programming and releasing for small-group distribution old-fashioned C++ WinMain-based programming, as in Petzold's "Programming Windows 95". My experience has been using the Win32 API only.

Unfortunately for me, MS documentation indicates that Bluetooth LE is not supported in Win32, and only in WinRT.  Thus, this forces me to use something like C++/WinRT to access the API.

So, I took a shot at it by downloading the only available example of bluetooth LE access in C++ which I know of at all, which is  [Microsoft's C++WinRT UWP example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/bluetoothle/).

I got that running as one Visual Studio 2022 project, and, since I am looking for a non-UWP program, I tried putting the relevant stuff into another project, for which I used Microsoft VS2022's built-in template for a C++/WinRT Console.  When I try to stick into that what appearVS says  to be the key elements of the C++/WinRT UWP example, and make modifications to fix obvious problems, I have an error in the code which I have no idea how to fix:  it is on the several get_weak() calls, which VS intellisense says are "undefined".  (The compile also fails with unable to find main.g.h and main.g.cpp .

Here is the code:

File main.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "main.g.h"


    class find_devs
    {
        find_devs() {};

        
    private:
        
        
        std::vector<Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation> UnknownDevices;
        Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher{ nullptr };
        event_token deviceWatcherAddedToken;
        event_token deviceWatcherUpdatedToken;
        event_token deviceWatcherRemovedToken;
        event_token deviceWatcherEnumerationCompletedToken;
        event_token deviceWatcherStoppedToken;

        void StartBleDeviceWatcher();
        void StopBleDeviceWatcher();
        
        std::vector<Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation>::iterator FindUnknownDevices(hstring const& id);

        fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_Added(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation deviceInfo);
        fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_Updated(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfoUpdate);
        fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_Removed(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfoUpdate);
        fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&);
        fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_Stopped(Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceWatcher sender, Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const&);
    };
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;

#include "pch.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "main.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;

namespace winrt
{
    hstring to_hstring(DevicePairingResultStatus status)
    {
        switch (status)
        {
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::Paired: return L"Paired";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::NotReadyToPair: return L"NotReadyToPair";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::NotPaired: return L"NotPaired";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::AlreadyPaired: return L"AlreadyPaired";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::ConnectionRejected: return L"ConnectionRejected";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::TooManyConnections: return L"TooManyConnections";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::HardwareFailure: return L"HardwareFailure";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::AuthenticationTimeout: return L"AuthenticationTimeout";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::AuthenticationNotAllowed: return L"AuthenticationNotAllowed";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::AuthenticationFailure: return L"AuthenticationFailure";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::NoSupportedProfiles: return L"NoSupportedProfiles";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::ProtectionLevelCouldNotBeMet: return L"ProtectionLevelCouldNotBeMet";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::AccessDenied: return L"AccessDenied";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::InvalidCeremonyData: return L"InvalidCeremonyData";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::PairingCanceled: return L"PairingCanceled";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::OperationAlreadyInProgress: return L"OperationAlreadyInProgress";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::RequiredHandlerNotRegistered: return L"RequiredHandlerNotRegistered";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::RejectedByHandler: return L"RejectedByHandler";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::RemoteDeviceHasAssociation: return L"RemoteDeviceHasAssociation";
        case DevicePairingResultStatus::Failed: return L"Failed";
        }
        return L"Code " + to_hstring(static_cast<int>(status));
    }
}


    // This scenario uses a DeviceWatcher to enumerate nearby Bluetooth Low Energy devices,
    // displays them in a ListView, and lets the user select a device and pair it.
    // This device will be used by future scenarios.
    // For more information about device discovery and pairing, including examples of
    // customizing the pairing process, see the DeviceEnumerationAndPairing sample.

#pragma region UI Code

   
   
   
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Device discovery
    /// <summary>
    /// Starts a device watcher that looks for all nearby Bluetooth devices (paired or unpaired). 
    /// Attaches event handlers to populate the device collection.
    /// </summary>
    void find_devs::StartBleDeviceWatcher()
    {
        // Additional properties we would like about the device.
        // Property strings are documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff521659(v=vs.85).aspx
        auto requestedProperties = single_threaded_vector<hstring>({ L"System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", L"System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected", L"System.Devices.Aep.Bluetooth.Le.IsConnectable" });

        // BT_Code: Example showing paired and non-paired in a single query.
        hstring aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices = L"(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{bb7bb05e-5972-42b5-94fc-76eaa7084d49}\")";

        deviceWatcher =
            Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation::CreateWatcher(
                aqsAllBluetoothLEDevices,
                requestedProperties,
                DeviceInformationKind::AssociationEndpoint);

        // Register event handlers before starting the watcher.
        deviceWatcherAddedToken = deviceWatcher.Added({ get_weak(), &DeviceWatcher_Added });
        deviceWatcherUpdatedToken = deviceWatcher.Updated({ get_weak(), &DeviceWatcher_Updated });
        deviceWatcherRemovedToken = deviceWatcher.Removed({ get_weak(), &DeviceWatcher_Removed });
        deviceWatcherEnumerationCompletedToken = deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted({ get_weak(), &DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted });
        deviceWatcherStoppedToken = deviceWatcher.Stopped({ get_weak(), &DeviceWatcher_Stopped });

        
        // Start the watcher. Active enumeration is limited to approximately 30 seconds.
        // This limits power usage and reduces interference with other Bluetooth activities.
        // To monitor for the presence of Bluetooth LE devices for an extended period,
        // use the BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher runtime class. See the BluetoothAdvertisement
        // sample for an example.
        deviceWatcher.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops watching for all nearby Bluetooth devices.
    /// </summary>
    void find_devs::StopBleDeviceWatcher()
    {
        if (deviceWatcher != nullptr)
        {
            // Unregister the event handlers.
            deviceWatcher.Added(deviceWatcherAddedToken);
            deviceWatcher.Updated(deviceWatcherUpdatedToken);
            deviceWatcher.Removed(deviceWatcherRemovedToken);
            deviceWatcher.EnumerationCompleted(deviceWatcherEnumerationCompletedToken);
            deviceWatcher.Stopped(deviceWatcherStoppedToken);

            // Stop the watcher.
            deviceWatcher.Stop();
            deviceWatcher = nullptr;
        }
    }

   
    std::vector<Windows::Devices::Enumeration::DeviceInformation>::iterator FindUnknownDevices(hstring const& id)
    {
       
    }

    fire_and_forget find_devs::DeviceWatcher_Added(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformation deviceInfo)
    {
        
        
    }

    fire_and_forget find_devs::DeviceWatcher_Updated(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfoUpdate)
    {
       
        // Protect against race condition if the task runs after the app stopped the deviceWatcher.
        if (sender == deviceWatcher)
        {
            

            auto deviceInfo = FindUnknownDevices(deviceInfoUpdate.Id());
            if (deviceInfo != UnknownDevices.end())
            {
                deviceInfo->Update(deviceInfoUpdate);
                // If device has been updated with a friendly name it's no longer unknown.
                
            }
        }
    }

    fire_and_forget find_devs::DeviceWatcher_Removed(DeviceWatcher sender, DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfoUpdate)
    {
        

        // Protect against race condition if the task runs after the app stopped the deviceWatcher.
        if (sender == deviceWatcher)
        {
           

            auto deviceInfo = FindUnknownDevices(deviceInfoUpdate.Id());
            if (deviceInfo != UnknownDevices.end())
            {
                UnknownDevices.erase(deviceInfo);
            }
        }
    }

    fire_and_forget find_devs::DeviceWatcher_EnumerationCompleted(DeviceWatcher sender, IInspectable const&)
    {
       
        // Protect against race condition if the task runs after the app stopped the deviceWatcher.
        if (sender == deviceWatcher)
        {
            
        }
    }

    fire_and_forget DeviceWatcher_Stopped(DeviceWatcher sender, IInspectable const&)
    {
        // Access this->deviceWatcher on the UI thread to avoid race conditions.
        auto lifetime = get_strong();
        co_await resume_foreground(Dispatcher());

        // Protect against race condition if the task runs after the app stopped the deviceWatcher.
        if (sender == deviceWatcher)
        {
           
        }
    }
#pragma endregion



int main()
{
    init_apartment();
    Uri uri(L"http://aka.ms/cppwinrt");
    
    printf("Hello, %ls!\n", uri.AbsoluteUri().c_str());
}
```

and, for completeness, this is pch.h

```
#pragma once
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
```

The code is, I know, not complete.  I haven't created a DeviceWatcher, etc., but I am apparently blocked in that I can't get the get_weaks() to pass intellisense screening or to compile.

Any guidance from people who know about this stuff would be great.

Bear in mind: I, myself, pretty much don't know what's going on. Due to the complexity, from my Win32 Petzold-style background, of the example MS C++/WinRT UWP example. It has all kinds of stuff in the Solution Explorer.  There are .idl files, a packages.config, a bunch of different Xaml files, some generated c++ files.  All this stuff is beyond my understanding, and I have not been able to pick it up with any speed from the MS documentation I can find.

(All I have figured out is that C++/WinRT is some sort of a thing where there are generated header and perhaps other files that are supposed to make your C++ code look like it's directly accessing WinRT classes. And, I have seen MS write that you can use winRT in non-UWP applications. Otherwise, I am lost.)

Comment: Would it be possible to post your full reproducing project somewhere (like github) to test?

Comment: Hi Simon,

Sounds like you may get into the details, or expect someone else may be so motivated.

I was afraid of GitHub, even though I have an account, because clicking on "setup a Github project" yielded a request for a string of permissions that looked extensive, and didn't understand.

But, I stuck the project-type and my .cpp / .h files on my old website, precisely here:

https://nasmusicsoft.com/ForStackExchange/ if anyone feels highly motivated.

(PS: somehow the full project iwith is like 450 Mbytes--no room for that!)